# How can I manipulate the form-group and controls divs with django-crispy-forms?

Tags: django, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3, django-crispy-forms

I'm using Django 1.8 and Crispy-Forms with Twitter Bootstrap 3

Here's what I have at the moment:

```
self.helper.layout = Layout(
    ...
    'address',
    StrictButton('Find address', id='find_address', css_class='btn-primary'),
)
```

This outputs:

```
<div id="div_id_address" class="form-group">
    <label for="id_address" class="control-label">Address</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input class="textinput textInput form-control" id="id_address" maxlength="100" name="address" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
</div>
<button id="find_address" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Find address</button>
```

What I'd like to output (class `form-inline` and button `find_address` added to the `controls div`):

```
<div id="div_id_address" class="form-group">
    <label for="id_address" class="control-label">Address</label>
    <div class="controls form-inline">
        <input class="textinput textInput form-control" id="id_address" maxlength="100" name="address" type="text" value="" />
        <button id="find_address" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Find address</button> 
    </div>
</div>
```

This aligns the button with the input field. Is it possible to achieve this with crispy-forms? I can't figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps

```
FieldWithButtons(
    'address', 
    StrictButton('Find address', id='find_address', css_class='btn-primary')
)
```

Could be solution.

See http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/layouts.html#bootstrap-layout-objects

Comment: Thanks Yuri, that's what I went with temporarily, but I'm still looking for a way to output a separate button inline with the field.